# Why do I have categories with duplicate slugs?

Tags: posts, categories, tags

I have inherited a WordPress site, where I'm trying to resolve a weird-looking issue related to post categories.

In the `Edit Post` page, there is nothing showing up under `Categories` (Gutenberg editor).

[image: missing categories]

Thinking this is strange, I went to the `Categories` page. There, I saw many categories with the same slug.

[image: list of duplicate posts]

This is even more strange to me, since I thought categories couldn't have the same slug. I figure this is where the issue lies.

So I'd like to start deleting these duplicate categories, but there is no `Delete` link – only `View`.

[image: view button visible, but not delete]

Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening here? Can I fix this directly in the database somehow?

Comment: That's super-strange. I think you're going to have to take a look at the database to figure this one out. My best guess is there are some IDs in the term tables that are misaligned or missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few rows in the `wp_terms` table with a `term_id` of `0`.

There was also some entries in `wp_term_taxonomy` with `term_taxonomy_id` and `term_id` both set to `0`.

After deleting all of those rows, behaviour returned to normal.

Also, I had to fix some issues with the database structure. In the `wp_terms` table, I had to make sure that `AUTO_INCREMENT` was enabled for the primary key field.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note: There will **not** be a delete option on a category on the Category page if posts are assigned to that category.  (**Added** see below.)

If you want to delete a category, you have to first change those posts to another category. You can do this on the Posts page, sort by category, then a Quick Edit to change the category.

Once there are categories without posts, then you can delete that category.

Changing the values in the table may cause other problems. Probably not severe, but I would guess that you have many posts without categories because you deleted those items in the table.

**Added**

Apparently the current version of WP allows you to delete categories that have posts assigned.

I recall that not being the case in prior version - 4.9-ish - but cannot tell the exact version. It was within the last year, though.

Answer modified with this new information.

Comment: The screenshot in the original post shows that all of these categories do, in fact, have a count of 0.

Comment: @SamNabi OK. But the info might be useful to others who have categories they want to remove. Thanks.

Comment: @RickHellewell This answer isn't true, I'm afraid. You can delete terms that have posts assigned to them. And you can clearly see, that `wp_delete_term` takes care of that and it removes deleted term from all posts it was assigned to: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1744

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż  while you can programmatacally delete terms that have posts assigned to them, I was  referring to trying to delete categories via the Admin, Categories page. On my test system (plain vanilla), I cannot delete categories if they have posts assigned - again, via Admin, Categories page.

Comment: @RickHellewell are you sure it’s original and clean WP? I’m looking at 3 sites of my clients right now - I can delete any term form admin on any of that site in wp-admin. I can do exactly the same on my WordPress.com account, so... The only category I can’t delete is the one that is set as default category...

Comment: Hmm....you are correct; re-checked another plain test site, and now you can delete categories that have posts assigned. I recall not being able to do that in prior versions; don't know which version, but probably a 4.9-ish version. I'll fix my answer.